# Sort by a specfic field on html output

Tags: html, powershell

I would like to sort the html results by the column named Distribution Point.  How would I go about this?

```
foreach ($result in $results)
{

if ($sccmContent | where-object { $_.PackageID -eq $result.PackageID })
{
    $package = $sccmContent | where-object { $_.PackageID -eq $result.PackageID }
    $packageSize = $([math]::Round($package.PackageSize/1024, 2))
    $packageSizeUnit = "MB"

    if ($packageSize -gt 1000)
    {
        $packageSize = $([math]::Round($packageSize/1024, 2))
        $packageSizeUnit = "GB"
    }
}
$failure = New-Object PSObject
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'ContentType' -Value $package.__CLASS.Replace('SMS_', '')
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'PackageID' -Value $result.PackageID
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'DistributionPoint' -Value $result.ServerNALPath.split('\\')[2].split('.')[0]
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'PackageName' -Value $package.Name
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'PackageSize' -Value "$($packageSize) $($packageSizeUnit)"
$failure | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'LastFailure' -Value $([System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::todatetime($result.SummaryDate))

$failures += $failure

}

$failures | ft

if ($failures)
{
#HTML Email Style
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt;}"
$style += "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style += "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style += "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style += "</style>"

$body = "<html><font face='Calibri' size='10pt'>"
$body += "The following packages have failed to distribute to the specified Distribution Points:<br /><br />"
$body += $failures | ConvertTo-Html -head $style
$body += "<br /><br />"

Send-MailMessage -smtpserver $smtpserver -from $from -to $to -subject "SCCM Content Distribution Failures" -body $body -bodyashtml
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this by using the `Sort-Object` cmdlet. For your specific code you could change this line:

```
$body += $failures | ConvertTo-Html -head $style
```

To:

```
$body += ($failures | Sort-Object DistributionPoint) | ConvertTo-Html -head $style
```